# android implement missing hardware OptionsMenu button

Tags: android, options-menu

I'm new in the world of android. Until now each and every "OptionsMenu" could be created like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_list_view_controller, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                startActivity(new Intent (ListViewControllerActivity.this, PreverencesActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_devsettings:
                startActivity(new Intent (ListViewControllerActivity.this, DevPreferencesActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

But now , for example, the new htc one have no hardware OptionsMenu button. When the OptionsMenu is implemented like my source, the menubutton inside the display won't show up.
How can implement the OptionsMenu right, that no additional button in the layout is needed?
Or can this button inside the display somehow be activated?

**EDIT:**
I think I gave a little less information to solve the problem, because the android won't take care of it in API 16 Jelly Bean.
So again. I've implemented the option menu like above. But now with the "htc one" which has no hardware option menu button, the in-screen option menu button doesn't show up.

Here is my layout xml, which i'm using (it could be a layout problem):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#1e4870"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_above="@+id/img_bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/img_bottom_bar"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
         android:src="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/footer_img_bs"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/footer_img_bs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here the part of the manifest, which i thought would solve this problem:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

I've also googled this problem many times. But it seems that i'm the only person around here with that problem. So i have to be a little stupid or something.

Before I forget: Thank you WebnetMobile.com for trying to help me. It could be that i'm just (like i've said before) too stupid to understand your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem like [this](http://techblog.rokoder.com/android-missing-menu-button/) link describes. You can simply change the "targetSdkVersion" from 16 to 10.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about **options menu**, not context menu (context menu is when you i.e. long tap list view item). You shall not bother if device got menu button or not. Android will take care of it for you and if your app will be running on i.e. Honeycomb and never version of android (which drops menu button), yet your app would need it, Android will show on-screen menu button

Comment: First: I'm sorry you're rigth it is an option menu not an contexmenu *facepalm*
Second: if I understand you, you mean that i have nothing to do and it will work... but that is not the case...

Answer (score 0):

switched to action bar in 3.0 + in case of options menu

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
   android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

use menu xml like that for compatability
so that it will be shown when menu button is clicked in 3.1- 
while supporting the upper verssions
for further details reffer android developers site
   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html